# how to access two different database from single web application

Tags: asp.net, database, database-connection

how to access two different database from single web application
using  asp.net .

can u suggest me a solution

Comment: What kind of database are you connecting to?

Comment: How are you connecting to the database even... this ought to be massively trivial (just a different connection string) that you're asking suggests that its not.

Answer (score 1):

Just go for any ORM tool like [LLBLGen](http://www.llblgen.com/), [nHibernate](http://nhforge.org/) etc...